# Linux "passwd" command can not force expire the password for the LDAP

Tags: linux, ldap, passwd

I have basic of setup of LDAP. Users can log and change of their password (passwd user_name) but when I am trying force expire the password: password -e uesr_name I can not do it. I got the error: does not exist in /etc/passwd. Where is the problem and how I can solved it?

Comment: Have you try with `usermod -e <DATE>`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov usermod with -e flag is for `set account expirantion` not for password expiration

Comment: I would class that as a bug. However, does https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/PwdMustChange help?